# c# get extract Strings from object[,] excel source

Tags: c#, string, range, import-from-excel

I'm looking for a way to parse an excel file in order to import some data into my DB table. 
While searching, I got this answer [Efficient method to enumerate cells in an Excel workbook using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261374/efficient-method-to-enumerate-cells-in-an-excel-workbook-using-c-sharp) but failed to get it working.

This is my code :

```
private void ImportFromSheet(Worksheet worksheet)
    {
        Object[,] rangeData = (System.Object[,])worksheet.UsedRange.Cells.get_Value(Type.Missing);            

        if (rangeData != null)
        {
            int iRowMax = rangeData.GetUpperBound(0);
            int iColMax = rangeData.GetUpperBound(1);

            for (int iRow = 2; iRow < iRowMax; iRow++) // skipping headers
            {
                Import( rangeData, iRow );
            } 
        }
    }
```

As you can see, this is directly taken from the answer I refered to before.

And in my Import function, I have a lot of these funny things :

```
string var = Convert.ToString(rangeData[iRow, index]) ?? string.Empty;
```

So, if I inspect rangeData[iRow, index] value in Visual Studio, I'm getting correct data, but at some point Convert.ToString fails to deliver me a string to assign to var (which seems unassigned at all).

Moreover, I tried this code :

```
for (int iCol = 1; iCol < iColMax; iCol++)
{
    string key = Convert.ToString(rangeData[1, iCol]) ?? "empty";
    string value = Convert.ToString(rangeData[2, iCol]) ?? "empty";
    Response.Write(iCol + " -> " + key + " : " + value + "<br />");
}
```

And it worked just fine.

So please, can you see what I'm missing ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Can you post the `Import` method itself? you pass `(rangeData, iRow)` but then you use `ToString(rangeData[iRow, index])...` - what is `index`?